# Arrow function with mysterious parentheses function at end is confusing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am confused by this function:

```
const today = ( d => new Date() )(new Date);
```

So I am not sure where to read about this and I am not sure what this is even called. So I apologize for the terrible question title. Anyways, I am confused as to what the `(new Date)` is doing at the end of the function here. Can someone point me to a reference to what is happening here or explain it to me.

I understand the `new Date()` mumbo jumbo. It is really just the purpose and functionality of `(new Date)` at the end that is tripping me up.

Comment: This is just an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8228281/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking the function immediately after creating it like IIFE, so the result variable will contain the result you passed. You are doing the same thing with the arrow function.

In the below example both expressions are the same. It’s invoking the function immediately:

```js
const today = d => console.log(d);
today(new Date)
```

```js
const today = ( d => console.log(d) )(new Date());

// In ES5 normal IIFE

(function(d){
  console.log(d);
})(new Date())
```

Comment: trying to add expalnation

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a simple function which accepts an parameter with name `d` and returns a `new Date`

```js
const f = d => new Date();

console.log(f());
```

Then you call this function immediately with `()` passing a new `Date` object, which is *unused* in the function

This code is equivalent

```
const today = (d => new Date())(new Date)
```

to this

```
const func = d => new Date();
const today = func(new Date);
```

In the first part with one line the difference is that you have lost the the function which you have created, because it was not assigned to anything. You have created and called it immediately.

Comment: Ok. That is super obvious. Thanks. I just wasn't seeing it.

Comment: Here what is the intention of passing the new Date() as an argument If it is unused?

Comment: @Vineesh what's the purpose of creating a function in the first place when you could just do `const today = new Date()` ?  My guess is there is more that is going on and this is only a building block in some book or tutorial.

Comment: Now i can turn it into something like this `const yesterday = ( d => new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate()-1)) )(new Date);`

Comment: Developers don't write the way they do out of purpose, they write code the way they do out of habit.  At least that's my observation of non-senior dev coworkers.

@Thomas Valadez - Or you could save everyone the trouble of reading that nonsense and use a semantic library like momentjs

Comment: thanks @aaaaaa for your comment. I am just trying to understand the syntax of ES6 and how to work with it. That way maybe someday I can contribute to a library like momentjs.

Answer (score 1):

```
const today = ( d => new Date() )(new Date);
▙▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▟   ▙▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▟ ▙▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▟
    ▐                  ▐               ▐
 variable     function definition    function invocation/call
```

- `today` will hold the value returned by the anonymous function
- the anonymous function will dissipate into the ether
- first the anonymous function will take a pointless `new Date` argument, completely disregard it and return a `new Date()` value (to be assigned to `today`)

Answer (score 1):

This looks more confusing that it actually is. If we broke it down:

```
// The following function returns a new Date
// regardless of any arguments passed to it

const someFunction = d => newDate();

// This could also be written as
const theSameFunction = () => newDate();
```

An IIFE ([immediately invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)) is one that is run *immediately* upon definition. This can be accomplished by wrapping an anonymous function in parenthesis, and calling it:

```
( () => console.log('Hello world') )();

// prints 'Hello world' to the console
```

Putting all that together:

```
const today = ( d => new Date() )(new Date);
// The d argument here is useless,
// since it is never used in the return of the IIFE

const alsoToday = ( () => new Date() )();
// This achieves the same effect as the first IFFE
```